# C# picturebox's loading time

Tags: c#, winforms

The game screen background contains a lot of pictureboxes and it takes 2-3 seconds to completely show the background after start, minimazing and moving. Is this code bad for my purpose? Is there another way to do this? Thank you. Here is the code:

```
public class gameArea
{
    private Panel gameArea;
    private MemoryStream ms;

    public gameArea(Panel gameArea)
    {
        this.gameArea = gameArea;
    }

    public void setBackground()
    {
        byte[] b_grass = File.ReadAllBytes(ImageFile.grassBG);
        byte[] b_tree = File.ReadAllBytes(ImageFile.tree);
        byte[] b_sea = File.ReadAllBytes(ImageFile.sea);

        // [650/50=13, 550/50=11]
        int[,] tile_id = { 
                         { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0 },
                         { 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0 },
                         { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 },
                         { 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
                         { 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0 },
                         { 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1 },
                         { 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0 },
                         { 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2 },
                         { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0 },
                         { 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2 },
                         { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0 }
                         };
        // tree id = 1
        // sea id = 2

        this.ms = new MemoryStream(b_grass);
        this.gameArea.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        this.gameArea.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

        for (int yIndex = 0, y = 0; y < this.gameArea.Height; y += 50, yIndex++)
        {
            for (int xIndex = 0, x = 0; x < this.gameArea.Width; x += 50, xIndex++)
            {
                switch (tile_id[yIndex, xIndex])
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            setTile(b_tree, x, y);
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            setTile(b_sea, x, y);
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setTile(byte[] b_img, int x, int y)
    {
        this.ms = new MemoryStream(b_img);
        PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
        pic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        pic.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        pic.Location = new Point(x, y);
        this.gameArea.Controls.Add(pic);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is not too much you can do for this kind of project. Visual C# wasn't really designed for games, but there are a few ways you can speed things.

1.) If your games does not need to change backgrounds, load it initially and only reset the pictures that you need to (maybe use a boolean in the tag value to determine if you should redraw.)

2.) Use [threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). If you start maybe 5 threads your rendering will probably speed up about 3 times.

3.) Convert your three images to Image objects in your constructor, this way you don't need to convert them for every tile.

Comment: Threading will only help on a multi-core machine.  Otherwise it will actually run slower.

Comment: very true, but most machine are multi-core now that we have hit the power/heat limit.

Comment: just be careful with my options. #1 is a bit tricky to implement and will only help if you are redrawing the background after every frame, #2 is also tricky to implement but does pay of on multicore machines, and #3 should help in all cases but the pay off might not be as great as you would expect. Optimizing takes a lot of trial and error so don't forget to make multiple implementations and test which one is the fastest (seriously, don't delete your old code to try something new, just make a method with a different name until you are happy with one particular method.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of many picture boxes, why not create one big bitmap and copy your small images into that.

Comment: If your background does not change, this is a good way to go.

Comment: Even though i do this, there can be a lot of image in this big image.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I found to (re)draw many pictureboxes is to set them all on a panel and set visible = false for the panel. After you are done with the pictureboxes set visible to true for the panel. This is around 50 times during redraws when the window is resized in my app with around 400 pictureboxes for the game of Go.

I have a pabel below that that becomes visible for like a quick flash set to the same general color so you see no flickering from the general color of the pictureboxes to a white background.